# Create a dataframe by discarding intersections of two dataframes (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Does anyone know of an efficient way to create a new dataframe based off of two dataframes in Python/Pandas?

What I am trying to do is check if a value from df1 is in df2, then do not add the row to df3. I am working with student IDS, and if a student ID from df1 is in df2, I do not want to include it in the new dataframe, df3.

So does anybody know an efficient way to do this? I have googled and looked on SO, but found nothing that works so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column is called ID.

```
df3 = df1[~df1["ID"].isin(df2["ID"])].copy()
```

Comment: It is called student, but I will definitely give this a try!

Comment: df3 = df1[!df1["student"].isin(df2["student"])].copy()
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What do you think I can do about this, btw the syntax error is where the ! is

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it uses a ~ instead of !

Comment: Oh ok, yeah that makes more sense with how Python works!

Comment: I fixed my solution.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have both dataframes of same length you can also use:

print df1.loc[df1['ID'] != df2['ID']]

assign it to a third dataframe.